# python BeautifulSoup4 break for loop when tag found

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a problem breaking a for loop when going trough a html with bs4.
I want to save a list separated with headings.
The HTML code can look something like below, however it contains more information between the desired tags:

```
<h2>List One</h2>
<td class="title">
    <a title="Title One">This is Title One</a>
</td>
<td class="title">
    <a title="Title Two">This is Title Two</a>
</td>
<h2>List Two</h2>
<td class="title">
    <a title="Title Three">This is Title Three</a>
</td>
<td class="title">
    <a title="Title Four">This is Title Four</a>
</td>
```

I would like to have the results printed like this:

```
List One
This is Title One
This is Title Two
List Two
This is Title Three
This is Title Four
```

I have come this far with my script:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib2.urlopen('some webiste')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

quote1 = soup.h2
print quote1.text

quote2 = quote1.find_next_sibling('h2')
print quote2.text

for quotes in soup.findAll('h2'):
    if quotes.find(text=True) == quote2.text:
        break
    if quotes.find(text=True) == quote1.text:
        for anchor in soup.findAll('td', {'class':'title'}):
            print anchor.text
            print quotes.text
```

I have tried to break the loop when "quote2" (List Two) is found. But the script gets all the td-content and ignoring the next h2-tags.
So how do I break the for loop with next h2-tag?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the problem lies in your HTML syntax. According to https://validator.w3.org it's not legal to mix "td" and "h3" (or generally any header tag). Also, implementing list with tables is most likely not a good practice.

If you can manipulate your input files, the list you seem to need could be implemented with "ul" and "li" tags (first 'li' in 'ul' containing the header) or, if you need to use tables, just put your header inside of "td" tag, or even more cleanly with "th"s:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Your title</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Your data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If the input is not under your control, your script could perform search and replace on the input text anyway, putting the headers into table cells or list items.

Comment: sorry I was unclear with my problem description. The Html is from some website. I cannot edit it.

Comment: In this case it gets a little hackish. Do the tags that interest you share the level in document tree (as shown in your example)? In that case this should help: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways
(find the first "h2", iterate its "next_siblings" which is a list-like object, for every iterated item see if it's "td" or "h3" or whatever interests you and ignore the rest)